# is it still not possible to delete folders in the file browser?

Tags: file-browser

seems to work with files, but not with folders. very tedious, as you have to go back to your os browser and cleanup what you couldnt do from within blender.

found a year old question here which was answered that it's not possible. is it still not possible somehow? in 2.73?

thanks

Comment: No. This is still not possible. See [this thread on the mailing list](http://blender.45788.x6.nabble.com/Why-can-t-blender-delete-directories-td121668.html). However if I understand correctly, the required capability was [recently added](https://developer.blender.org/rB414c70435dcd52eb67df59f56132837de0a63b64) to blender's internal delete function, so AFAIK it's just a matter of creating a higher level delete operator. Perhaps It'll be here soon.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick answer. seems like it's in the making then :). cool.

Comment: @gandalf3 Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is still not possible as of 2.73.

See [this thread](http://blender.45788.x6.nabble.com/Why-can-t-blender-delete-directories-td121668.html) on the bf-comitters mailing list for some discussion on why this is.

If I understand correctly, the required capability was [recently added](https://developer.blender.org/rB414c70435dcd52eb67df59f56132837de0a63b64) to blender's internal delete function, so AFAIK it's more or less a matter of creating a higher level recursive delete operator. Perhaps It'll be here soon.